# Storing data in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save User details in `UserDefaults` using below method but it crashes on `archiver.encode(assistantContact,forKey: "assistantContact")`.
I tried making AssistantContact as class instead of Struct but still it didn't worked.
How to archive AssistantContact too in order to save them in User ?

```
  struct AssistantContact {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: [String]
}

struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var email: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var company: String
    var assistantContact: AssistantContact
}

extension User {
    func encode() -> Data {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
        archiver.encode(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        archiver.encode(lastName, forKey: "lastName")
        archiver.encode(email, forKey: "email")
        archiver.encode(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
        archiver.encode(company, forKey: "company")
        archiver.encode(assistantContact, forKey: "assistantContact")
        archiver.finishEncoding()
        return data as Data
    }

    init?(data: Data) {
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        defer {
            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
        guard let firstName = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as? String else { return nil }
        guard let lastName = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "lastName") as? String else { return nil }
        guard let email = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String else { return nil }
        guard let phoneNumber = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "phoneNumber") as? String else { return nil }
        guard let company = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "company") as? String else { return nil }
        guard let assistantContact = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "assistantContact") as? AssistantContact else { return nil }
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.email = email
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.company = company
        self.assistantContact = assistantContact

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error that it gives?

Comment: It crashes on archiver.encode(assistantContact, forKey: "assistantContact")

Comment: @Nitesh show your archive code and also how you're calling `User` struct?

Comment: Seriously, don't do this.  Use CoreData or some other more appropriate data store.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a `NSObject` and then use this method for archiving data.
Replace the `archiver.encode(assistantContact, forKey: "assistantContact")` with `archiver.archivedData(withRootObject: assistantContact)`

and use this for unarchive `unarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: assistantContact)`

Comment: I'm using struct. Its giving error 'Static member 'archivedData' cannot be used`

Comment: @Nitesh you can store the data in `NSObject`. This will solve the issue.

Comment: @Nitesh if you getting the data from server then try archiving the whole data and unarchiving it whenever required.